# PDF data extraction gives symbols/gibberish?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, text-extraction

I have a piece of software called PDF2XL which is normally great for extracting tables of data from PDF files.  I've used it with hundreds of files before.

This one file though, gives me gibberish output that I can't even copy and paste into this textarea correctly.  All sorts of unicode weirdness.

If I copy and paste as per normal into excel/notepad I get the same issue.

I assume it's something to do with a messed up character encoding header in the PDF file?  How can I change this?  I'm on Windows and have no software that can edit PDFs, so if I need to edit/re-save it, please recommend a free piece of SW to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share a link to the file? I'll try to find out what might be the issue.

Answer (score 6):

There are an increasing number of PDF files the used subsetted fonts which is basically a custom encoding.  Normally the font descriptor in the PDF should have a ToUnicode table to allow the text extraction to decode the font encoding and return the correct text.

Some PDF producers are doing this on purpose to prevent easy PDF text extraction for things such as financial reports.  If there is only one font then you could manually decode the font but in my experience I have seen PDF's with multiple random encodings which makes it nearly impossible to decode automatically.

One way to test for these types of PDF's is to open the file in Acrobat, select some text, copy it and then paste it into Notepad.  If the text is garbled then the PDF is using a subsetted font and there is not much more you can do.  If Acrobat can't extract the text correctly then nothing else can.  It may as well be a page of hieroglyphs.

Comment: Just come across this problem again.  Googled it and the top hit was my own SO question.  I think the solution is to take screenshots and run it through OCR software instead...

Comment: You can also render the PDF page to an image file if your OCR results are not accurate enough via the screenshots.

Comment: How do you do that Andrew? In this instance they were, but it'd be good to know, and possibly easier too. Thanks